# My function doesn't get called from handleChange on react-redux app

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I need to make a form to submit one of several choices and i need to use react-redux so i cannot use local state to change the choice selected

the app does work (which means componentdidmount is working) but if a select one of the choices i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setModelSelector(data)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
   this.props.selectCar(event.target.value)//the function doesn't get called
    //this.props.setModelSelector(data)
    event.preventDefault();
  }

handleChange(event) {
   //this.props.selectCar(event.target.value)
    this.props.setModelSelector(data)//Even if i run the same function of componentDidMount i get the same error
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

I have also checked `event.target.value` contains indeed the string that i need to change the value showed in the form

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
 handleChange
src/components/ModelDetailsContainer.js:40
   37 | 
    38 | handleChange(event) {
   39 |  // this.props.selectCar(event.target.value)
 > 40 |   this.props.setModelSelector(data)
      | ^  41 |   event.preventDefault();
    42 | }
   43 |
```

Comment: @RandyCasburn i don't think it's a duplicate because in none of the answers it  tells you to use arrow functions, which was the solution to my problem.

Comment: Arrow functions are an alternative because they don't bind the `this` keyword. either solution (binding or arrow functioin) will work. And now you know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is getting rebound in your event handler. Either change `handleChange(event) {` to `handleChange = event => {`, or do `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);` in your constructor.